# JQuery | How to get attributes of iframe from other html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get

I want get the attribute 'src' of a iframe from other html.

I can get the attribute of a iframe in the same html but not from other html,

look my code:

```
/////////iframe attribute from the same html//////////

   var Mframe_src = $("#Mframe").attr('src');

   alert(Mframe_src);

//////////iframe attribute from other html////////////

var frame_Ads = $("#Mframe").contents();

var Ads_src = frame_Ads.find("#ads");

alert(Ads_src.attr('src')); /// the alert present me undefined
```

Comment: what do you mean with "other html" ?

Comment: `"other html"` Other domain???

Comment: is the iFrame from the same domain as the main HTML?

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible, you could try to get the iframe content by ajax though and then do something with that.

```
$.get("my iframe page").success(data){
//do something
});
```